# Unable to connect to sql server 2008 with jdbc

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a sql server with JDBC in java.

My server uses a windows authentication.

I use this code:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://MYPC\\MYSERVER;databaseName=MYDB;integratedSecurity=true";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

In my classpath i have the file:
jtds-1.3.1.jar and sqljdbc4.jar

And i have a VM argument:

```
-Djava.library.path="SQLPATH\jtds\x64\SSO"
```

When i run the code, i have this exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unable to connect to the host MYPC
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: remove \\MYSERVER after MYPC. This is mine: sqlserver://MYSERVER;databaseName=DB_NAME (I've connected with SQL authetication)

Answer (score 0):

The URL syntax is jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]

Did you try to ping your host using ping command ? Or try with IP address.

Comment: i'm sure that the sql server is running. I checked it in the configuration manager, and i can use it with Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

If `//MYPC\\MYSERVER` is a network path, I'd imagine it needs to look like this:

```
\\MYPC\\MYSERVER
```

Of course, if the SQL Server 2008 instance is setup as the default instance, the `\\MYSERVER` portion isn't necessary.